# Почему вылетает NullPointerException

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток. Сижу, пишу отправку комментария на сайт uCoz. Имеется

```
HashMap<String, String> postAttributes;
```

В котором будут храниться параметры для отправки HttpPost запроса. Собственно, когда я пробегаюсь по содержимому исходного кода страницы сайта, то работает такой условник:

```
if(tmpline.indexOf("ssid") != -1) {
    String tmpValue = tmpline.substring(tmpline.indexOf("ssid") + 6, tmpline.indexOf("',a:'"));
    Log.d("myLogs", "ssid: " + tmpValue);
    postAttributes.put("ssid", tmpValue);
}
```

А в логах вижу:

```
ssid: KqZ8itfD
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ru.n_torrents.client.SendCommentTask.getPostAttributes(SendCommentTask.java:139)
```

Строка 139 это postAttributes.put("ssid", tmpValue);
Вот, собственно и вопрос: почему так происходит? В лог печатает, а в HashMap положить стесняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А postAttributes только объявлена или объявлена и инициализирована? Инициализирована в том плане, что

```
HashMap<String, String> postAttributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Если только объявлена - вот и ответ.

Comment: Да, забыл отписать, проинициализирована) Главное, падает именно на этом параметре, на других - все в порядке.

Comment: А это условие часом не может отработать до инициализации? В другом потоке или что-нибудь подобное.

Comment: не, у меня есть метод, работающий в фоне, в нем я инициализирую все временные и объекты, потом запускаю метод для поиска параметров HttpPost запроса. Проблему я решил, в гугле наткнулся на ссылку другого сайта (stackoverflow), почистил проект - больше такой ерунды не вылетает))